# How to count and plot a cumulative number over a date range by groups

Tags: r

I want to find the best way to plot a chart showing the cumulative number of individuals in a group based on the date they came into the group as well as the date they may have left the group. This would be within the minimum and maximum date ranges of the date values. Each row is a person.

```
group_id    Date_started    Date_exit
1           2005-06-23      NA
1           2013-03-17      2013-09-20    
2           2019-10-24      NA  
3           2019-11-27      2019-11-27
4           2019-08-14      NA
3           2018-10-17      NA
4           2018-04-13      2019-10-12
1           2019-07-10      NA
```

I've considered creating a new data frame with a row per day within the min/max range and then applying some kind of function to tally the groups totals for each row (adding and subtracting from a running total based on whether or not there is a new value in either of the columns) but I'm not sure if one, that's the best way to approach the problem and two, how to practically run the cumulative count function either.

Ultimately though I want to be able to plot this as a line chart so I can see the trends over time for each group as I suspect one or more of them are much more volatile in terms of overall numbers. So again I'm not sure if *ggplot2* has something already in place to handle this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Do you want to plot the number of people in the group with respect to time ?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that's not clear. I want a running total of the numbers of people in each of the groups at each date. As people come in and out of the group this number will fluctuate and I need to see this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you will need to create a dataframe with the desired dates and count, for each group, how many individuals are in the group.

I quickly put this together, so I'm sure there's a more optimal  solution, but it should be what you're looking for.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # for melt

# your data
test <- read.table(
  text = 
"group_id,Date_started,Date_exit
1,2005-06-23,NA
1,2013-03-17,2013-09-20
2,2019-10-24,NA
3,2019-11-27,2019-11-27
4,2019-08-14,NA
3,2018-10-17,NA
4,2018-04-13,2019-10-12
1,2019-07-10,NA",
h = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F
)

# make date series
from <- min(as.POSIXct(test$Date_started))
to <- max(as.POSIXct(test$Date_started))
datebins <- seq(from, to, by = "1 month")

d_between <- function(d, ds, de){
  if(ds <= d & (de > d | is.na(de)))
    return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}

# make df to plot
df <- data.frame(dates = datebins)
df[,paste0("g", unique(test$group_id))] <- 0

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  for(j in seq_len(nrow(test))){
    gid <- paste0("g", test$group_id[j])
    df[i, gid] <- df[i, gid] + d_between(df$dates[i], test$Date_started[j], test$Date_exit[j])
  }
}


# plot
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars = "dates"), aes(dates, value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + theme_bw()
```

This gives:

[image]

Feel free to play with the date bins (in `seq()`) as necessary.

**EDIT : for loop explanation**

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  for(j in seq_len(nrow(test))){
    gid <- paste0("g", test$group_id[j])
    df[i, gid] <- df[i, gid] + d_between(df$dates[i], test$Date_started[j], test$Date_exit[j])
  }
}
```

The first loop iterates over the chosen dates.
For each date, go through the dataframe of interest (`test`) with the second for loop and use the custom `d_between()` function to determine whether or not an individual is part of the group. That function returns a boolean (which can translate to 0/1). The value 0 or 1 is then added to the `df` dataframe's column corresponding to the appropriate group (with `gid`) at the date we checked (row `i`).

Note that I'm considering the individuals as part of the group as soon as they join (`ds <=  d`), but are not a part of the group the day they quit (`de > d`).

Comment: Great, got it working thanks. If you don't mind would you explain a bit more about the construction of the for loop statement and specifically the role of appending a 'g' character as an prefix/id. What does that do?

Comment: Appending a 'g' was just so that the column names in the df start with a letter (it can cause unforeseen issues if you have numbers that are actually characters as col names). I'll edit my answer for the explanation on the for loops

Comment: Looking at this closer its not quite producing the results I expected, the plot for each group doesn't start at zero as I would expect. I'll update the question with an image from of the graph.

Comment: @AlexCraig Ah yes, now that you mention it, it's my bad. I put return TRUE by default when the exit date was NA ! meaning if the checked date is before that person entered, it would count as true. Let me fix that.

Comment: @AlexCraig I've updated it. It should work as intended now. sorry about that. I went a bit too fast :-)

Comment: Yes! that's it. Thank you so much for your help. I'm working through the your approach to make sure I understand it fully and can implement again in the future.